# Font in Lighttable is not displaying properly

Tags: lighttable

I have fresh installation of Lubuntu 18.04 and downloaded the newest version of Lighttable. When I open the editor, the displayed fonts has lots of artifacts, but is readable. The font in the file dialog is made up entirely of those unicode place holder for missing codepoints.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The first screenshot corresponds to [#2343](https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable/issues/2343) and the second to [#2368](https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable/issues/2368).

Subscribe to these issues to be notified of their resolutions.